# Find most similar sets efficiently (Python, data structures)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I have a couple thousand Python sets in a list called `my_sets`. For every set "A" in `my_sets`, I want to find the five sets (sets "B") in `my_sets` that contain the highest percentage of set A's members.

I'm currently storing the data as sets and looping over them twice to calculate overlap...

```
from random import randint
from heapq import heappush, heappop

my_sets = []

for i in range(20):
    new_set = set()

    for j in range(20):
        new_set.add(randint(0, 50))

    my_sets.append(new_set)

for i in range(len(my_sets)):
    neighbor_heap = []

    for j in range(len(my_sets)):
        if i == j:
            continue

        heappush(neighbor_heap, (1 / len(my_sets[i] & my_sets[j]), j))

    results = []

    while len(results) < 5:
        results.append(heappop(neighbor_heap)[1])

    print('Closest neighbors to set {} are sets {}'.format(i, results))
```

However, this is obviously an O(N**2) algorithm, so it blows up when `my_sets` gets long. Is there a better data structure or algorithm that can be implemented in base Python for tackling this? There is no reason that `my_sets` has to be a list, or that each individual set actually has to be a Python set. Any way of storing whether or not each set contains members from a finite list of options would be fine (e.g., a bunch of bools or bits in a standardized order). And building a more exotic data structure to save time would also be fine.

(As some people will likely want to point out, I could, of course, structure this as a Numpy array where rows are sets and columns are elements and cells are a 1/0, depending on whether that element is in that set. Then, you'd just do some Numpy operations. This would undoubtedly be faster, but I haven't really improved my algorithm at all, I've just offloaded complexity to somebody else's optimized C/Fortran/whatever.)

**EDIT** After a full test, the algorithm I originally posted runs in ~586 seconds under the agreed test conditions.

Comment: When you make `my_sets` longer, do you also make the sets or the random range larger? Or will they stay this small?

Comment: Good question. The length of `my_sets` is theoretically boundless, but will probably top out at 10k in practice (and that would be an extreme case). Each set will contain no more than ~200 items (in an extreme case), and the union of all the sets would likely be no more than ~1000 items (again, in an extreme case).

Comment: Why not, @StefanPochmann? I'm open to correction.

Comment: Hmm, or at least it's not obviously O(N**2). It would require `heappush` to be O(1), and I don't think it is. Maybe if you limit the set sizes by a fixed constant then you can not only consider the intersection operation to be O(1) but it also makes `heappush` O(1), but at least that's not obvious.

Comment: Are you only interested in the intersection?  If you you are open to using a metric that is symmetric, and also satisfies the triangle inequality, then you can likely use BK tree.

Comment: @James I'm actually interested in the length of the intersection as a percent of the length of scan A's set. So, the triangle inequality is not satisfied. I was trying to simplify the question, but that was an important detail. My apologies. I'm not familiar with BK trees specifically, but a lot of trees I've seen used for this sort of thing (e.g., Ball trees) seem to have a high setup cost on your initial data, but then they're fast at finding nearest neighbors for a never-before-seen set/observation, which doesn't help with the initial pairwise comparison, right?

Comment: For BK trees, the build process still follows the tree search which is at worst N log(N)

Comment: @StefanPochmann You're right, it's worse than O(N**2)... but I'd still like to eliminate the double-loop squared part...

Comment: @James Thanks, I will look into performance characteristics of BK trees (and verify for other kinds of common trees as well). We may be on to something here.

Comment: So if we change the limits from 20, 20, 50 to 10000, 200, 1000, would that be representative and we could use that as benchmark?

Comment: @Stefan, yes, that should be a reasonable benchmark.

Comment: Your test case has 20 sets, each with 20 elements drawn from a possible 50.  Is that representative ?  I wonder if it helps to "invert" the data, so that for each element value you know what sets it appears in.  Then you can scan the elements in each set, and find what sets it intersects with, and by how much.  But that only helps if the number of elements per set is small compared to the number of sets and the number of sets per element is likewise small.

Comment: @ChrisHall Sounds like the question and answer in the first two comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you:

1. invert the sets, to produce for each set element, a list (or set) of the sets which contain it.

   which is **O**(*n***m*) -- for *n* sets and on average *m* elements per set.
2. for each set *S*, consider its elements, and (using **1**) construct a list (or heap) of other sets and how many elements each one shares with *S* -- pick the 'best' 5.

   which is **O**(*n***m***a*), where *a* is the average number of sets each element is a member of.

How far removed from **O**(*n***n*) that is obviously depends on *m* and *a*.

**Edit**: Naive implementation in Python runs in 103 seconds on my machine...

```
old_time = clock()

my_sets = []

for i in range(10000):
    new_set = set()

    for j in range(200):
        new_set.add(randint(0, 999))

    my_sets.append(new_set)

my_inv_sets = [[] for i in range(1000)]

for i in range(len(my_sets)):
    for j in range(1000):
        if j in my_sets[i]:
            my_inv_sets[j].append(i)

for i in range(len(my_sets)):
    counter = Counter()

    for j in my_sets[i]:
        counter.update(my_inv_sets[j])

    print(counter.most_common(6)[1:])

print(clock() - old_time)
```

Comment: Edited Chris' answer to include a naive implementation in code, as I didn't want to post a different answer and not have him get credit for his idea. Not sure if that's a best practice around here, apologies if it's not. I was able to get test results in under 2 minutes, which is about a 10x speedup.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom: a 10x speedup is gratifying :-)  Is it giving the right answer ?  No problem with the edit :-)  But -- _assuming it does indeed work_ -- can you add in your previous best time ?

Comment: After a full test, the original algorithm was 586 seconds. So, more like a 6x speedup. Still, impressive, thanks! I'm stepping out for lunch, but I'll likely accept this answer when I get back, barring no additional input.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom: FWIW, it occurs to me that in step 2, the operation on each set _S_ is entirely independent, so it would be straightforward to run as many threads as you have CPUs for.

Comment: I also found [a Python implementation](https://github.com/1e0ng/simhash) of the [SimHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimHash) algorithm, which can be used to quickly estimate the similarity between sets.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the number of passes through the set list by building a list of set indexes associated to each value.  Then, one additional pass through the set list, you can determine which sets have the most common values by compiling the number of indexes for each value of a set.

This will improve performance in some cases but, depending on the density of the data it may not be a huge difference.

Here is an example using defaultdict and Counter from the collections module.

```
from collections import defaultdict,Counter
def top5Matches(setList):
    valueSets = defaultdict(list)
    for i,aSet in enumerate(setList):
        for v in aSet: valueSets[v].append(i)
    results = []
    for i,aSet in enumerate(setList):
        counts = Counter()
        for v in aSet: counts.update(valueSets[v])
        counts[i] = 0
        top5      = [setList[j] for j,_ in counts.most_common(5)]
        results.append((aSet,top5))
    return results
```

In order to compare execution times I took the liberty of embedding your solution in a function. I also had to make a fix for cases where two sets would have no intersection at all:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop
def OPSolution(my_sets):
    results = []
    for i in range(len(my_sets)):
        neighbor_heap = []
        for j in range(len(my_sets)):
            if i == j: continue
            heappush(neighbor_heap, (1 / max(1,len(my_sets[i] & my_sets[j])), j))
        top5 = []
        while len(top5) < 5:
            j = heappop(neighbor_heap)[1]
            top5.append(my_sets[j])
        results.append((my_sets[i],top5))    
    return results
```

Both function return a list of tuples containing the original set and a list of the top 5 sets based on number of common values.

The two functions produce the same results although the top 5 sets may not be the same when the intersection count is the identical for a 6th (or more) additional sets.

```
from random import randrange

my_sets = [ set(randrange(50) for _ in range(20)) for _ in range(20) ]
opResults = OPSolution(my_sets)
print("OPSolution: (matching counts)")
for i,(aSet,top5) in enumerate(opResults):
    print(i,"Top 5:",[len(aSet&otherSet) for otherSet in top5])
print("")

print("top5Matches: (matching counts)")
t5mResults = top5Matches(my_sets)
for i,(aSet,top5) in enumerate(t5mResults):
    print(i,"Top 5:",[len(aSet&otherSet) for otherSet in top5])
print("")
```

Output:

```
OPSolution: (matching counts)
0 Top 5: [8, 7, 7, 7, 6]
1 Top 5: [7, 6, 6, 6, 6]
2 Top 5: [8, 7, 6, 6, 6]
3 Top 5: [8, 7, 7, 6, 6]
4 Top 5: [9, 8, 8, 8, 8]
5 Top 5: [7, 6, 6, 6, 6]
6 Top 5: [8, 8, 8, 7, 6]
7 Top 5: [8, 8, 7, 7, 7]
8 Top 5: [9, 7, 7, 7, 6]
9 Top 5: [8, 8, 8, 7, 7]
10 Top 5: [8, 8, 7, 7, 7]
11 Top 5: [8, 8, 7, 7, 6]
12 Top 5: [8, 7, 7, 7, 7]
13 Top 5: [8, 8, 8, 6, 6]
14 Top 5: [9, 8, 8, 6, 6]
15 Top 5: [6, 6, 5, 5, 5]
16 Top 5: [9, 7, 7, 6, 6]
17 Top 5: [8, 7, 7, 7, 7]
18 Top 5: [8, 8, 7, 6, 6]
19 Top 5: [7, 6, 6, 6, 6]

top5Matches: (matching counts)
0 Top 5: [8, 7, 7, 7, 6]
1 Top 5: [7, 6, 6, 6, 6]
2 Top 5: [8, 7, 6, 6, 6]
3 Top 5: [8, 7, 7, 6, 6]
4 Top 5: [9, 8, 8, 8, 8]
5 Top 5: [7, 6, 6, 6, 6]
6 Top 5: [8, 8, 8, 7, 6]
7 Top 5: [8, 8, 7, 7, 7]
8 Top 5: [9, 7, 7, 7, 6]
9 Top 5: [8, 8, 8, 7, 7]
10 Top 5: [8, 8, 7, 7, 7]
11 Top 5: [8, 8, 7, 7, 6]
12 Top 5: [8, 7, 7, 7, 7]
13 Top 5: [8, 8, 8, 6, 6]
14 Top 5: [9, 8, 8, 6, 6]
15 Top 5: [6, 6, 5, 5, 5]
16 Top 5: [9, 7, 7, 6, 6]
17 Top 5: [8, 7, 7, 7, 7]
18 Top 5: [8, 8, 7, 6, 6]
19 Top 5: [7, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Comparing execution times for various combinations of setting shows that the indexing by value performs better on larger data sets (albeit not by much in some cases):

[EDIT] Added Chris Hall's solution to measure the speed improvements provided by limiting the functionality to sets of values in a consecutive range.  I also had to embed it in a function and test that results were the same. I realized while doing it that, we essentially had the same approach. The main difference is that Chris uses a list instead of a dictionary which constrains the values to a range() for which the size must be provided.

```
def chrisHall(my_sets,valueRange):
    results = []
    my_inv_sets = [[] for i in range(valueRange)]
    for i in range(len(my_sets)):
        for j in range(valueRange):
            if j in my_sets[i]:
                my_inv_sets[j].append(i)

    for i in range(len(my_sets)):
        counter = Counter()

        for j in my_sets[i]:
            counter.update(my_inv_sets[j])

        top5 = [my_sets[j] for j,_ in counter.most_common(6)[1:]]
        results.append((my_sets[i],top5))
    return results
```

Performance tests were also embedded in a function to avoid repeating the boilerplate code:

```
from random import randrange
from timeit import timeit

def compareSolutions(title,setCount,setSize,valueRange,count=1):

    print("-------------------")
    print(title,setCount,"sets of",setSize,"elements in range 0 ...",valueRange)
    testSets = [ set(randrange(valueRange) for _ in range(setSize)) for _ in range(setCount) ]

    t = timeit(lambda: chrisHall(testSets,valueRange),number=count)
    print("chrisHall",t)

    t = timeit(lambda: top5Matches(testSets),number=count)
    print("top5Matches",t)

    t = timeit(lambda: OPSolution(testSets),number=count)
    print("OPSolution",t)

compareSolutions("SIMPLE TEST SET",20,20,50,count=100)
compareSolutions("MORE SETS:",2000,20,50)
compareSolutions("FEWER INTERSECTIONS:",2000,20,500)
compareSolutions("LARGER SETS:",2000,200,500)
compareSolutions("SETTING FROM COMMENTS:",10000,200,1000)
```

Results:

```
-------------------
SIMPLE TEST SET 20 sets of 20 elements in range 0 ... 50
chrisHall 0.0766431910000005
top5Matches 0.07549873900000037
OPSolution 0.05089954700000021
-------------------
MORE SETS: 2000 sets of 20 elements in range 0 ... 50
chrisHall 1.274499733999999
top5Matches 1.2646208220000013
OPSolution 3.796912927000001
-------------------
FEWER INTERSECTIONS: 2000 sets of 20 elements in range 0 ... 500
chrisHall 0.4685694170000012
top5Matches 0.42844527900000173
OPSolution 3.5187148479999983
-------------------
LARGER SETS: 2000 sets of 200 elements in range 0 ... 500
chrisHall 8.538208329
top5Matches 8.51855685
OPSolution 23.192823251999997
-------------------
SETTING FROM COMMENTS: 10000 sets of 200 elements in range 0 ... 1000
chrisHall 190.55364428999997
top5Matches 176.066835327
OPSolution 829.934181724
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used set intersection to find the common elements, and then sort this elements based on the number of common elements they contain,
Here's a code you might want to try:

```
from random import randint
from heapq import heappush, heappop

my_sets = []
for i in range(20):
    new_set = set()

    for j in range(20):
        new_set.add(randint(0, 50))

    my_sets.append(new_set)


for i in range(len(my_sets)):
    temp = dict()
    for j in range(len(my_sets)):
        if i == j:
            continue

        diff = my_sets[i] & my_sets[j]
        temp[j] = diff

    five = sorted(temp.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda s: len(s[1]))[:5]
    five_indexes = [t[0] for t in five]
    print('Closest neighbors to set {} are sets {}'.format(i, five_indexes))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not 100% certain if sorting or using the heap is faster (so this may admittedly be a very minor speedup), but it doesn't solve the underlying problem of doing `N**2` set intersections, which will still be slow as molasses for big sets and large values of N.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler and a bit faster (looks like 5-10% on the large case with limits 10000, 200, 1000) to use `heapq.nlargest`:

```
for i in range(len(my_sets)):
    results = nlargest(5,
                       (j for j in range(len(my_sets)) if j != i),
                       key=lambda j: len(my_sets[i] & my_sets[j]))
    print('Closest neighbors to set {} are sets {}'.format(i, results))
```

This doesn't build a heap with N-1 elements but with [just 5 elements](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c3536b79425edc623860073eed4cf8945b2281dc/Lib/heapq.py#L398).

Comment: Possibly faster with `sum(1 for x in my_sets[i] if x in my_sets[j])` instead of `len(my_sets[i] & my_sets[j])`?

Comment: @tobias_k Appears to be 3-4 times *slower*. Why did you think it might be faster? The original way can choose which set to iterate and which set to check, and it's written in C.

Comment: @tobias_k Ah, I guess because it doesn't have to build a set. Anyway, faster version `sum(map(my_sets[j].__contains__, my_sets[i]))` is still about 2.3 times slower than the original.

Comment: Yeah, guess being implemented in C kind of outweights the new set creation...